# Filter Multi-Column ListBox based on Value in TextBox

Tags: listbox, userform

I have a userform with a multi-column listbox with 9 columns.
I have a textbox: txtShopOrdNum. The values for txtShopOrdNum appear in Column 2 of the listbox.

Currently, the value in txtShopOrdNum does not change the listbox. However, now, I would like the listbox to filter based on the value of txtShopOrdNum, so only the matching row appears in the listbox. Can this be done without adding too much code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following code to work. I'm a newbie so if there is a better way to write this, I welcome the suggestion(s). I hope this may help others.

```
'Search Button
Private Sub cmbSearch_Click()
    'Filters a 9-column listbox (lstMaster) to ONLY show the ONE row for the Shop Order Number searched. 
    Dim sat As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim deg1 As String
    Dim deg2 As String
    Dim RN As Integer
    
    With lstMaster 'Need to clear the listbox first
            .Clear
            .ColumnCount = 120
            .ColumnWidths = "0;0;0;100;120;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;75;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;110;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;40;0;0;0;0;0;0;60;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;"
            'Must include the total ColumnCount and all ColumnWidths for the code to work. ColumnWidths = 0 do not appear in the listbox. 
    End With

    'redacted irrelevent code here
    
    deg2 = txtShopOrdNum.Value 'Shop Order Number being searched
    RN = 5 'column number of Shop Order Numbers
    For sat = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row  '4 = first row of databody to the first blank row
        deg1 = Cells(sat, 5) 'lower bound (last) value in column 5
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            lstMaster.AddItem
                For c = 0 To 118 'c is the total number of columns
                    lstMaster.List(s, c) = Cells(sat, c + 1)
                Next c
                s = s + 1 's is the count of the results
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @JeremyCaney I'll do my best. I am very new with VBA and so much I've gleened from this site. I'll take a look at the code and see if there is some additional details I can add. If there is something specific you would like to see, please advise.